# Cant deleteMany documents inside a MongoDB with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create a script which is going to delete documents in collections but remain the collection itself (just make 0 documents inside a collection).
When I run the script with node it just runs but didn't do anything at all. No errors.

**Code:**

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Sorry unable to connect to MongoDB Error:', err);
    } else {

        async function deleteListingsScrapedBeforeDate() {
            result = await client.db("CryptoCurrencies").collection("who")
                .remove({});
            console.log(`${result.deletedCount} document(s) was/were deleted.`);
            await deleteListingsScrapedBeforeDate();
        }
    }

});
```

Also is there a way to have a script which is going to delete all documents in multiple collections? Can I declare a collections like an array?

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code the function `deleteListingsScrapedBeforeDate()` is never actually called (also if it were called this would result in an endless recursion). You should change this to:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

async function deleteListingsScrapedBeforeDate(db) {
   await db.collection("who").remove({});
   console.log(`${result.deletedCount} document(s) was/were deleted.`);            
}

(async function() {

  const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

  const dbName = '<dbname>';
  let client;

  try {

    client = await MongoClient.connect(url);    
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    await deleteListingsScrapedBeforeDate(db);
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }

  if (client) {
    client.close();
  }
})();
```

Comment: Damn, my bad, was totally done after day of coding. Thank you for solution, that's working one. Help's me a lot!